# Dynamically show a DatePicker

Tags: java, swing, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8

I am writing a JavaFX application which shows a table of `StringProperty` and `ObjectPropery<LocalDate>` values. As I dig into how tables work, it appears I cannot use a `DatePicker` as a cell, so what I plan to do is show dates as a string, but when a user tries to edit that cell, I capture that event and show a dynamic `DatePicker` which will accept a new date value and update the cell.

Now, I am having trouble getting this dynamic `DatePicker` to show up.

JavaFX:

```
    <TableView fx:id="tableView" editable="true" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
        <columns>
         ...
        <TableColumn fx:id="recDate" onEditStart="#handleChangeDate" prefWidth="100.0" text="Received Date">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="recDate" />
                <!-- <DatePicker fx:id="recDatePicker" /> -->
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
         ...
```

Java 8:

```
@FXML
private void handleChangeDate(CellEditEvent<MissionItem, LocalDate> e) {
    final DatePicker dp = new DatePicker(e.getOldValue());
    dp.setDisable(false);
    dp.setOnAction(event -> {
        LocalDate date = dp.getValue();
        System.out.println("Selected date: " + date);
    });
    Platform.runLater(dp::show);
    dp.show(); //redundant. Still doesn't work.
    System.out.println("fired event");
}
```

I am able to see `fired event` however the `DatePicker` never shows up.

My goal is:

- Display the table as a set of Strings/LocalDates
- Assuming a cell cannot itself be a DatePicker, great an event handler such that when the user wants to edit a date cell, a dynamic DatePicker shows up, accepts user input, and the value updates.
- Ensure this scales for 1000's of rows.

Comment: You need to add the `DatePicker` to the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For customizing a column's cells you need to create appropriate `TableCell`s in the `cellFactory` of this column:

```
public class DatePickerTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, LocalDate> {

    private final DatePicker datePicker;
    private boolean listening = true;

    // listener for changes in the datepicker
    private final ChangeListener<LocalDate> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (listening) {
            listening = false;

            TableColumn<T, LocalDate> column = getTableColumn();
            EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<T, LocalDate>> handler = column.getOnEditCommit();
            if (handler != null) {
                // use TableColumn.onEditCommit if there is a handler
                handler.handle(new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(
                        (TableView<T>) getTableView(),
                        new TablePosition<T, LocalDate>(getTableView(), getIndex(), column),
                        TableColumn.<T, LocalDate>editCommitEvent(),
                        newValue
                ));
            } else {
                // otherwise check if ObservableValue from cellValueFactory is
                // also writable and use in that case
                ObservableValue<LocalDate> observableValue = column.getCellObservableValue((T) getTableRow().getItem());
                if (observableValue instanceof WritableValue) {
                    ((WritableValue) observableValue).setValue(newValue);
                }
            }

            listening = true;
        }
    };

    public DatePickerTableCell() {
        this.datePicker = new DatePicker();
        this.datePicker.valueProperty().addListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            listening = false;
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            listening = false;
            setGraphic(this.datePicker);
            this.datePicker.setValue(item);
            listening = true;
        }
    }

    public static <E> Callback<TableColumn<E, LocalDate>, TableCell<E, LocalDate>> forTableColumn() {
        return column -> new DatePickerTableCell<>();
    }

}
```

Note that this class does not react to "normal" editing states. It's always in editing state. It does however attemt to call the `onEditCommit` handler to enable handling editing for non-observable properties.

The factory can be added via fxml using

```xml
<TableColumn fx:id="recDate" prefWidth="100.0" text="Received Date">
    <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="recDate" />
    </cellValueFactory>
    <cellFactory>
         <DatePickerTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn"/>
    </cellFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

(Requires and appropriate import instruction to be included in the fxml.)

Comment: This does work, however I am trying to fill in the original source value into the `DatePicker` constructor, however I am finding that the original values are all null?

Comment: `new DatePicker(this.getItem());` the `this.getItem()` is always returning null when it should at least be the original value that would have gone into the cell...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it works! I'm guessing the listener should have been set to true by default.

Comment: Assigning the value should be done in the `updateItem` method since initially all cells are empty and the item is `null`. However there was a bug in the code preventing the initial update. sorry about that.